# Program to resolve FCG membership

Tags: algorithm, math

Well I need help, I'm working with languages and free context grammars, and I need to know if there is an algorithm or program that helps to resolve membership issue, this means that giving an string "w" and a FCG G, decide if the string it's on the language or if is not.

I'm looking for a library or a program that can do this for later convert the string into an automata.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've only seen such grammars called context-free grammars, not free context grammars.  Also, automata is the plural of automaton.  Your last statement regarding converting a string into an automaton makes no sense.  There is a correspondence between context-free grammars and pushdown automata, but not between strings and automata.  Given a context-free grammar, the simplest algorithm, which may not be the most efficient, for deciding if a string is part of the language of the grammar would be to apply every possible production in the grammar to every possible non-terminal string that can be derived from the starting non-terminal.  Generate every possible string that of length less than or equal to the string in question.  If the string is not there, then it is not a member of the language of the grammar.